# swift 3 call observer with wrong value

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, xcode8

i work with swift 3 for osx
i added this Observer in my MasterViewController: `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(requestData), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "requestData"), object: nil)`

my fun requestData in the same MasterViewController:

```
func requestData(with predicate : NSPredicate? = nil) {

   let appdelegate = NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
   let context = appdelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
   let request = NSFetchRequest<Person>(entityName: "Person")
   request.predicate = predicate

   print(predicate)

   do {
      people = try context.fetch(request)
      tableView.reloadData()
   } catch { }
}
```

if i now call this observer from another view controller like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "requestData"), object: nil)
```

the print result "print(predicate)" will show:

```
Optional(NSConcreteNotification 0x608000246150 {name = requestData})
```

but this is wrong.
predicate have to be in this case nil.
what do i wrong?

Comment: The behavior is normal. if a parameter is specified in the selector, a notification passes itself in the parameter. Declare a separate method for the notification and call `requestData()` in there.

Comment: okay i thought something like that. but i need this extra function to call requestData like your way, or is it possible to do it in one way without an extra function ?

Comment: `Notification` is only useful if there are many receivers or source and destination are not related at all. If the controllers are related consider to use protocol / delegate or callback closure. There is also a block based API to add the observer.